# Paging helper ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paging

I have implemented a paging HTML helper (adapted from Steven Sanderson's book). This is the current code:

```
public static string PageLinks(this HtmlHelper html, int currentPage, int totalPages, Func<int, string> pageUrl)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++)
    {
        TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a");
        tag.MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl(i));
        tag.InnerHtml = i.ToString();
        if (i == currentPage)
            tag.AddCssClass("selectedPage");
        result.AppendLine(tag.ToString());
    }

    return result.ToString();
}
```

This produces a bunch of links to each page of my items. If there are many pages this can be a bit overwhelming. I am looking for a similar implementation which produces something less overwhelming like this:

```
<previous ... 5 6 7 ... next>
```

where 6 is the current page. I am sure someone must have implemented something similar, before I have to re-implement the wheel?